# Aspectj ltw aop.xml

Tags: java, eclipse

How can we use aop.xml to define pointcuts in a plain java code? This is a sample code in which am trying to define the pointcut in aop.xml->
1)This is the java class

```
package testAOP;

public class HelloWorld {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            HelloWorld app = new HelloWorld();
            app.say("Hello world!");
            app.add(11, 22);
        }

        private int add(int i, int j) { return i + j; }
        public void say(String message) { System.out.println(message); }
}
```

2)My aspect class

```
package testAOP;

abstract aspect MyAspect {


    protected abstract pointcut publicMethod();

    Object around() : publicMethod() {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPointStaticPart);
        return proceed();
    }
}
```

3)Have created META-INF folder in the main project directory folder i.e. in package testAOP->META-INF which consists of the aop.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<aspectj>
            <aspects>
        <concrete-aspect
            name="testAOP.ConcreteAspect"
            extends="testAOP.MyAspect"
        >
            <pointcut
                name="publicMethod"
                expression="execution(public * testAOP.HelloWorld.*(..))"
            />
        </concrete-aspect>
    </aspects>
            <weaver options="-verbose">
              <weaver options="-showWeaveInfo"/>
            </weaver>
</aspectj>
```

Have added the METAINF folder having the `aop.xml` to the java build path and in the run configurations for Aspectj load-time weaving have set the following properties:

- In Main tab Project->HelloWorldPlainJava ,Main class->testAOP.HelloWorld
- In Arguments tab VM arguments->-javaagent:"D:\Eclipse_fldr\eclipse\plugins\org.aspectj.weaver_1.7.3.20130613144500-a.jar"
- In LTWclasspath tab in user entries have added HelloWorldPlainJava.

What did i miss? WHy is not recognizing the pointcuts?

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve my problem, the aop.xml was missing in the bin folder and there was a version mismatch with the aspectjrt and aspect-weaver